# What do you call those areas in airports where people usually stand to see planes take off?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I'm referring to this:

[image: row of empty seats, shadow of man using a cell, overlooking runway]

[image: backs of two kids looking at airplanes parked on runway]

I thought of *pre-boarding platform* or *[waiting area](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/waiting%20area)* though I'm not very sure if I'm correct.

Comment: Observation Deck is the usual I believe.

Comment: Some airports have areas like these available for non-passengers as well, so I would certainly not refer to it in a way that implies it is always linked to boarding or waiting for a flight :)

Comment: It is the window of the waiting area.

Comment: The question and the pictures can be interpreted differently. The pictures you put seems like just waiting areas with windows. But there can be specifically designed observation lounges or decks also to watch the planes.

Answer (score 8):

It is known by many names.

- [Public viewing area](http://www.perthairport.com.au/AboutUs/PublicViewingArea.aspx)
- [Aviation gallery](http://www.changiairport.com/at-changi/entertainment-lifestyle/changi-aviation-gallery)
- [Observation deck](http://your.heathrow.com/viewheathrow-observation-deck-opens/)
- [Aircraft viewing area](http://www.birminghamairport.co.uk/useful-information/facilities2/aircraft-viewing-area.aspx)
- [Public observation area](http://www.yvr.ca/en/community-environment/community/community-engagement/Public-Observation-Area.aspx)

There is no standard, although the most common one is *viewing area*.

Comment: Are we talking about the general public, or only passengers and staff who have been cleared through security? I would think that airports and airlines would be nervous about letting unscreened people close to airliners, so are all of these only for screened passengers' use?

Comment: @PhilPerry Close? No. These aren't really close to any airplanes. And these are used to describe the area, whether or not they're for public or passenger use is down to the individual airport. There are some airports that have a Passenger Viewing Area and a Public Viewing Area.

Answer (score 3):

They are called *view platforms* if they are on top , often in the open air, but often  they are simply part of the waiting area  inside the airport like in your pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

We observe something standing at **Observation area**.

Comment: You're missing an article there, bud.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "observation room".